# i need to remove 1st single quote in this array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I created my function:

```
function call() {
    var value= [];
    var arr = data.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var a = "'" + arr[i] + "'";
        value.push(a);
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

output is coming like this:

```
value='a','b','c','d';
```

but i need like this:

```
value=a','b','c','d;
```

helps are mostly appreciable.  thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do such thing, but you could achieve this just by simply join with `','`

```
var arr = data.split(',');
alert(arr.join("','"))
```

*Simple code simple life :)*

Answer (score 4):

You can use ternary operator `?:` to put condition to add the starting quotes only after first element.

```
function call() {
    var value= [];
    var arr = data.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var a = (i!=0 ? "'" : "") + arr[i] + "'";
        value.push(a);
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

You can also update the first element and remove start quote after loop complete.

```
function call() {
    var value= [];
    var arr = data.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var a = "'" + arr[i] + "'";
        value.push(a);
        alert(value);
    }
    value[0] = value[0].substring(0,value[0].length);
    value[value.length-1] = value[value.length-1].substring(1, value[value.length-1].length-1);
}
```

Comment: using ternary operator is working i need to remove single quote for last array element also  like this i need : a,'b','c','d

Comment: The you may need the second solution using substring.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple regex replace

```
data.replace ("'[A-z]");
```

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator ?: at both places of adding single quote.

```
function call() {
  var value= [];
  var arr = data.split(',');
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = (i!=0 ? "'" : "") + arr[i] + (i!=arr.length-1 ? "'" : "");
    value.push(a);
    alert(value);
 }
}
```